# Progressbar on button click

Tags: android, progress-bar

So everything works in the code but i can not figure out how to increase the progressbar 1 unit at a time with the button clicks.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

        TextView txtCount;
        Button btnCount;
        int count=0;
        Chronometer chrono;
        boolean mIsStarted = false;
        ProgressBar probar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            chrono=(Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
            txtCount=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            btnCount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            probar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    count++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    btnCount.setEnabled(true);
                    if (!mIsStarted) {
                        chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        chrono.start();
                        mIsStarted = true;

                        probar.setProgress(count++);
                        probar.setMax(5);


                    }
                }
        });
    }}
```

I have been trying a stupid amount of things for hours and can not get it to work. It will count the first click but then stops counting the following clicks. I figured it would work similar to the textview methods but still can not figure it out! thanks for your answers!

Comment: try to learn how to debug it will help you alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will count the first click but then stops counting the following
>   clicks

Due to if block:

```
 if (!mIsStarted) {
  ...
  mIsStarted = true;
  ...
}
```

Because `mIsStarted` is `false` for first time only and for rest value of `mIsStarted` is `true`.

So either remove if condition or move ProgressBar related code outside if block to get it work on Button click.

Comment: nothing like being new at something to make you feel stupid! haha ty for your solution... forgot to check my brackets! ty!

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this condition in your `onClick()` method

```
mIsStarted = true;
```

See at first you have initialized `mIsStarted` to `false` so it works in first click but once it gets inside this condition here

```
 if (!mIsStarted) {
                    chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    chrono.start();
                    mIsStarted = true; // here it is initialized to true

                    probar.setProgress(count++);
                    probar.setMax(5);


                }
```

so now `mIsStarted` is `true` so it will not enter the above `if` and hence wont inrement the `progress bar`

So you can comment this statement `mIsStarted = true;` and then check